# Why can't I enter an integer value into a decimal field?

Tags: sql-server, casting, integer, decimal

I'm trying to write an insert statement for a SQL Server table that inserts the value 1 into a decimal field. The field is of the type decimal(10, 10) which, as far as I understand, means that it can have up to 10 digits altogether, and up to 10 of those digits can be after the decimal point. But, when I try to run the insert statement I get the following error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

If I change the data type of the field to decimal(11, 10), it suddenly works. What am I not understanding here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`decimal(10, 10)` means all decimal places, no digits to the left of the decimal point!

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(SQL.80).aspx_

> **decimal[(p[, s])]**
>
> **p (precision)**   Specifies the maximum total number of decimal digits
>   that can be stored, both to the left
>   and to the right of the decimal point.
>   The precision must be a value from 1
>   through the maximum precision. The
>   maximum precision is 38. The default
>   precision is 18.
>
> **s (scale)**   Specifies the maximum number of decimal digits that can be
>   stored to the right of the decimal
>   point. Scale must be a value from 0
>   through p. Scale can be specified only
>   if precision is specified. The default
>   scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p.
>   Maximum storage sizes vary, based on
>   the precision.

`decimal(11,10)` gives you 1 digit the the left of the decimal and 10 to the right, so integer 1 fits now!

**EDIT**

when using: `decimal(p,s)`, think of `p` as how many total digits (regardless of left or right of the decimal point) you want to store, and `s` as how many of those `p` digits should be to the right of the decimal point.

```
DECIMAL(10,5)=     12345.12345
DECIMAL(10,2)=  12345678.12
DECIMAL(10,10)=         .1234567891
DECIMAL(11,10)=        1.1234567891
```

Comment: I'm still confused. It says that scale is the " *maximum* number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point" - not that there has to be 10.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't mean it's a sliding decimal point.  The implication is if you provide less than 10 digits to the right, the rest are zeroes.

Comment: @Joe, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to say, but if you run `declare @x decimal(5,2);set @x=1.123456789;select @x;set @x=1;select @x` you will get `1.12` and `1.00`.  Once you declare a decimal, the number of digits to the left and to the right of the decimal point are fixed, there is no sliding of the decimal point.

Comment: @froadie, if you want 10 whole number digits and 10 decimal digits in a value: `1234567891.1234567891`, use `DECIMAL(20,10)`

Comment: @KM, I was responding to froadie's comment, not your post which I +1'd.